# android - dialogfragment using commitAllowStateLoss

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

What are the effects of commiting a dialogfragment transaction with state loss in android:  Since its just a simple error dialog im showing with an ok button to close it i dont think i need to worry about state loss.

in my DialogFragment subclass i've over rided the show class so that it commits to include state loss so that i dont get illegalstateException...

```
 @Override 
  public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
      FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
      ft.add(this, tag);
      //its just dialogs so  can we allow state loss to not trigger illegalStateExceptions
      ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)
Originally you are trying to avoid this error (Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState).

This error stems from the fact that these Bundle objects of the `onSaveInstanceState()` represent a snapshot of an Activity at the moment `onSaveInstanceState()` was called, and nothing more. That means when you call `FragmentTransaction#commit()` after `onSaveInstanceState()` is called, the transaction won't be remembered because it was never recorded as part of the Activity's state in the first place

You tried to work around that by using `commitAllowingStateLoss()`, let's discuss
the difference between calling `commit()` and `commitAllowingStateLoss()` is that the latter will not throw an exception if state loss occurs. Usually you don't want to use this method because it implies that there is a possibility that state loss could happen. The better solution, of course, is to write your application so that `commit()` is guaranteed to be called before the activity's state has been saved, as this will result in a better user experience. Unless the possibility of state loss can't be avoided, `commitAllowingStateLoss()` should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised no one ever gave a simple correct answer. The transaction will be lost. Since in this case you are adding a dialog fragment, *if* the fragments have to be restored, the dialog will be gone.

Test this by going into the developer settings and check 'never keep activities' or something that sounds a lot like that. Then go to your app, get the dialog open and press Home. Then open the app again.